# How to add allowed symbols on input field in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, input

I have my own create `input` tag which has to field for phone number:

```html
    <base-input
        style="margin-bottom: 15px; width: 100%; max-width: 510px;"
        v-model="phone"
        type="tel"
        placeholder="Mobile phone"
    />
```

How can I add only allowed symbols (0-9 and +). I was trying to use `pattern="[0-9]+"`, but it doesn't work. Also, as I know, it can be done with regular expressions, but I don't know how to use it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex `^[0-9+]+$`. It allows numbers and `+`

Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/4LQduG)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML input tag has a [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_pattern.asp) attribute that receives a RegEx.

for your case:

```
<input
style="margin-bottom: 15px; width: 100%; max-width: 510px;"
v-model="phone"
type="tel"
placeholder="Mobile phone" 
pattern="[0-9\+]+" title="Phone number - allowed symbols are (0-9 and +)" />
```

If the pattern does not match it will throw the title.